# How to get levels of a corresponding element of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to print the level of every list element in scheme in the following manner. 
List: '(1 (20 (3 (4 40) 3) 2) 1)
expected result: '(0 (1 (2 (3 4) 5) 6) 7)

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(define (print-level x current-level)
  (define (deeper x) (print-level x (+ current-level 1)))
  (define (same   x) current-level)    
  (define (print-element x)
    (if (list? x)
        (map deeper x)
        (same x)))
  (map print-element x))
```

Comment: Couldn't find the earlier solutions, may be was searching the wrong keywords. Thanks for the response Chris...will try the approach you have suggested :)